# Fibreglass/Plain Scuff Sheets - Are They a Good Idea?

Tags: cricket, equipment

I just have two quick questions about scuff sheets.

> (1) Are they worth having, ie do the give good protection and not hamper the performance of the bat?
>
> (2) If I were to get one, is it a good idea to get a plain one[1](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CRICKET-BAT-ANTI-SCUFF-PROTECTION-SHEET-CLEAR-PLAIN/231208545457?_trksid=p3984.c100052.m2206&_trkparms=aid=222006&algo=SIC.FITP&ao=1&asc=20140127092945&meid=6946490031954560612&pid=100052&prg=20140127092945&rk=2&rkt=4&sd=300837197165) or a fibreglass one[2](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/300837197165?var=600075614217&ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649)?

[Plain Sheet (eBay)](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/CRICKET-BAT-ANTI-SCUFF-PROTECTION-SHEET-CLEAR-PLAIN/231208545457?_trksid=p3984.c100052.m2206&_trkparms=aid=222006&algo=SIC.FITP&ao=1&asc=20140127092945&meid=6946490031954560612&pid=100052&prg=20140127092945&rk=2&rkt=4&sd=300837197165)

[Fibreglass Sheet (eBay)](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/300837197165?var=600075614217&ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649)

Any help would be most appreciated! :)

Note: I do already have protective tape to put on the edges also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no empirical evidence to back it up but I don't believe they hamper the performance of the bat and they do take some of the impact.  I have a five or six year old bat with a lot less horizontal cracking than I have previous had in bats of a similar vintage.  For what it's worth I'd recommend fitting it.  If you are going to fit it, take the tape off the edges first and then re-apply new tape after the anti scuff is on or it'll all get a bit messy.

Personally I use the clear one, it looks nicer for a start!  I think the best you can get is helicopter scuff sheet which is clear.  If you goto http://custombats.co.uk/cbforum/index.php and search for scuff sheet there you will find more than enough analysis of it!

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a good quality, but also cheap, scuff sheet? I saw on that forum that the eBay ones that are like £2 aren't exactly top-notch. Any recommendation?

Comment: I bought some off Bulldog Cricket but I haven't had used it yet so I can't recommend it as such, sorry! :-)